# Is the JobScheduler API over engineering for an alarm clock app?

Tags: android

So the job scheduler api is for tasks at a later time. It seems as if these tasks are meant to be like downloading from the internet at a certain time or whatever. I simply want to make an alarm clock app. Would this be over engineering?

What are the components necessary to activate and set an alarm at a later date? I want to be able to have my app set the alarm and activate it, not rely on another alarm clock app

edit:

according to http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html it seems as if alarmmanager is outdated and jobscheduler is its replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not only overengineering, `JobScheduler` won't really work well in your case.

`JobScheduler` is good if you want to schedule some tasks for later, and these tasks require some additional resources - like network. Also, relying on `JobScheduler` won't work for pre-Lollipop devices (but you can use `GcmNetworkManager` from Google Play Services as a replacement).

In your case `AlarmManager` will be enough. It's not deprecated - just some usecases that were usually implemented using `AlarmManager` are currently better supported by `JobScheduler` (like recurring tasks that require WIFI in order to succeed). This is also what article that you linked says.

Summarizing:

- `AlarmManager` is usually more reliable in terms of timing. Your code can run as the exact time you scheduled it to run. Sounds like a pretty important thing for an alarm app, huh?
- `AlarmManager` doesn't know anything about the state of a device - it's not a right choice if you want to perform some tasks in the future and they rely on a working Internet connection. JobScheduler covers that - but that's not your case.
- `JobScheduler` works on Android 5.0 and newer (but you can use `GcmNetworkManager` from Google Play Services as a replacement, in that case you drop support for devices distributed without Google Play, like Amazon phones).
- Android 6.0 introduced the Doze mode. This is a new battery-optimization mechanism that puts your device into sleep when it's not used for some longer period of time. `AlarmManager` has an ability to fire your code even if your phone is in Doze. `JobScheduler` has not.

Comment: hey i added an edit to my question. its a link that makes it seem as if alarmmanager is outdated and jobscheduler is its replacement

Comment: Actually the last point is false, you can override JobScheduler as important for Doze mode

Answer (score 0):

That doesnt seem like the right answer.  It may be made to work, but that seems more for scheduling jobs in a semi-realtime manner.  What you generally use for an alarm type app is just AlarmManager.

Comment: hey i added an edit to my question. its a link that makes it seem as if alarmmanager is outdated and jobscheduler is its replacement

Comment: Not at all.  JobScheduler is more about real time computing.  Which is a very different thing than mere alarm scheduling.  That's like saying bricks are obsolete building materials because we can build skyscrapers.